# National Visa Information

Tags: visa, germany

I have a type D visa, work permit for Germany after travelling from India. I got the visa via processing from the Indian employer. I am on deputation.

Now if I find another local employer in Germany who is offering a permanent job, is the work contract of the new employer enough for me to change/transfer the current visa to the new employer? Or do I have to apply for a new visa? Basically what is the process like?

My current work permit has the Indian employer's name under the remarks column, which means basically I can work only for that employer.